# Postgresql recursive self join

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My table in postgres looks like below, Table stores a chain sort of relation between IDs and I want to have a query which can produce the result like "vc1" -> "rc7" or "vc3"->"rc7", I will only query on the IDs in first column ID1

```
ID1     ID2
"vc1"   "vc2"
"vc2"   "vc3"
"vc3"   "vc4"
"vc4"   "rc7"
```

So I want to supply some "head" id here for which I have to fetch the tail(last in the chain) id.

Comment: Well: just join them resursively and anchor/restrict the head and tail to the {vc1,rc7} or {vc3,rc7} begin/end-conditions. BTW: is is not clear what you want, do you want the full path from {vc1,rc7}, or just a boolean that indicates the _existence_ of such a path ?

Comment: Hi @wildplasser! thanks for the direction, but I wish I could make full sense out of that. I am not skilled with sql. I cant understand the part anchor/restrict head or tail. I forgot to mention in the question but I will only be querying on the basis of some head id only.

Comment: @wildplasser And I do not want full path, I want to supply the head and want to fetch the tail.

Comment: Given the head, there may be more than one tail. In fact a whole tree. The question is not very clear (and shows no _effort_ at all) So your data is guaranteed to contain a linear and no loops ?

Comment: My bad to hurry in posting the question and not putting in much detail, by the design of application where it is used, more than one tail is not possible. So that part is assured.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is the SQL using a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive tr(id1, id2, level) as (
      select t.id1, t.id2, 1 as level
      from t union all
      select t.id1, tr.id2, tr.level + 1
      from t join
           tr
           on t.id2 = tr.id1
     )
select *
from (select tr.*,
             max(level) over (partition by id1) as maxlevel
      from tr
     ) tr
where level = maxlevel;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/11833/4) is the SQLFiddle

Comment: just exactly what I wanted! Thanks. never used WITH RECURSIVE/CTEs in the past.

Comment: Argh... Stack Overflow didn't bother loading your answer until I'd mostly finished mine, even though it was 8 hours ago. Posted anyway, as it can be a lot simpler.

Comment: @david_adler . . . You just have to select another version of Postgres:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/11833/1.

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid iterating the children of a child that has already been seen/marked?

Comment: @david_adler . . . Questions should be asked as new questions and not in comments, along with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Question, why do you use a join instead of an inner join, or is there no difference in this case? Super helpful btw thnx

Comment: @JustinFuruness . . . `join` means `inner join` and it is easier to type.

Comment: You can use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` if you want to skip duplicate rows.

Answer (score 42):

This is a classic use of a simple recursive common table expression (`WITH RECURSIVE`), available in PostgreSQL 8.4 and later.

Demonstrated here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/78e15/9

Given the sample data as SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("ID1" text, "ID2" text)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ("ID1", "ID2")
VALUES
    ('vc1', 'vc2'),
    ('vc2', 'vc3'),
    ('vc3', 'vc4'),
    ('vc4', 'rc7')
;
```

You could write:

```
WITH RECURSIVE chain(from_id, to_id) AS (
  SELECT NULL, 'vc2'
  UNION
  SELECT c.to_id, t."ID2"
  FROM chain c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 t ON (t."ID1" = to_id)
  WHERE c.to_id IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT from_id FROM chain WHERE to_id IS NULL;
```

What this does is iteratively walk the chain, adding each row to the `chain` table as from- and to-pointers. When it encounters a row for which the 'to' reference doesn't exist it will add a null 'to' reference for that row. The next iteration will notice that the 'to' reference is null and produce zero rows, which causes the iteration to end.

The outer query then picks up rows that've been determined to be the end of the chain by having a non-existent to_id.

It takes a bit of effort to get your head around recursive CTEs. They key things to understand are:

- They start with the output of an initial query, which they repeatedly union with the output of the "recursive part" (the query after the `UNION` or `UNION ALL`) until the recursive part adds no rows. That stops iteration.
- They aren't really recursive, more iterative, though they're good for the sorts of things you might use recursion for.

So you're basically building a table in a loop. You can't delete rows or change them, only add new ones, so you generally need an outer query that filters the results to get the result rows you want. You'll often add extra columns containing intermediate data that you use to track the state of the iteration, control stop-conditions, etc.

It can help to look at the unfiltered result. If I replace the final summary query with a simple `SELECT * FROM chain` I can see the table that's been generated:

```
 from_id | to_id 
---------+-------
         | vc2
 vc2     | vc3
 vc3     | vc4
 vc4     | rc7
 rc7     | 
(5 rows)
```

The first row is the manually added starting point row, where you specify what you want to look up - in this case that was `vc2`. Each subsequent row was added by the `UNION`ed recursive term, which does a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the previous result and returns a new set of rows that pair up the previous `to_id` (now in the `from_id` column) to the next `to_id`. If the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` doesn't match then the `to_id` will be null, causing the next invocation to return now rows and end iteration.

Because this query doesn't attempt to add only the *last* row each time, it's actually repeating a fair bit of work each iteration. To avoid that you would need to use an approach more like Gordon's, but additionally filter on the previous depth field when you scanned input table, so you joined only the most recent row. In practice this usually isn't necessary, but it can be a concern for very big data sets or where you can't create appropriate indexes.

More can be learned in [the PostgreSQL documentation on CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).

Comment: I thought this was a pretty good explanation of the same thing.
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-recursive-query/