# Create table of all children of a parent or set of parents in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of parent-child relationships, and want to produce a table that has all the children of a given parent or parents.

By the way, I have no idea how to create tables with stack overflow's markdown, I tried and failed.

Example 1:

Table name: relationship

```
Child_ID  Parent_ID  
 1         2  
 2         3  
 3         4  
 4         5  
 5         6  
 6         7  
 7         8  
 8         9  
 9        10  
10        11
```

So the resulting table should be, for Parent_ID 7:

```
Child_ID  Parent_ID  
 1         7  
 2         7  
 3         7  
 4         7  
 5         7  
 6         7
```

Or, perhaps using a table, selecting all children:

Join the following table of parents:

```
Parent_ID  
7  
9
```

Producing a result like this:

```
Child_ID  Parent_ID  
1         7  
2         7  
3         7  
4         7  
5         7  
6         7  
1         9  
2         9  
3         9  
4         9  
5         9  
6         9  
7         9  
8         9
```

... and of course I can just run a distinct if I wanted unique Child_ID's.

I'd offer an idea, but I have no idea where to begin, and I've looked everywhere for this.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: Have you looked at this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261792/postgresql-recursive-self-join

Answer (score 0):

You can us a [`RECURSIVE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) CTE. with array functions to create lists of the relationships.

Creating the data

```
SELECT child_id, parent_id
INTO temp table relations
FROM (VALUES  (1,  2),  
 (2,  3),  
 (3,  4),  
 (4,  5),  
 (5,  6),  
 (6,  7),  
 (7,  8),  
 (8,  9),  
 (9, 10),  
(10, 11) ) as t(child_id, parent_id)
```

Next the recursive CTE, we'll start with the initial relationship from the above table and then continue adding rows (with `UNION`) by joining a child to a parent:

```
WITH recursive children(child_id, parent_id) AS(
SELECT child_id, parent_id
FROM relations
UNION
SELECT relations.child_id, children.parent_id
FROM children
INNER JOIN relations ON relations.parent_id = children.child_id
-- SELECT chain_.parent_id, child_id || children
-- FROM chain_
-- INNER JOIN relations ON relations.parent_id = children[1]
)
SELECT * FROM children where parent_id = 7
```

Producing the result:

```
child_id | parent_id
---------+----------
     6   |     7
     5   |     7
     4   |     7
     3   |     7
     2   |     7
     1   |     7
```