# How to work with parents of rows in postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have table with two columns : `scopename` and its `parent name`.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qsajdyzs5hwt6zg/table.jpeg?dl=0

[image]

I want to get tree to get data in application easily .Like these

https://www.dropbox.com/s/48da6vg694estg8/table2.jpeg?dl=0

[image]

How can i do these ? please help me ! I can't change structure of db  or table .
P.S. I use `postgresql` .
P.S2. There simple part of table , there might be 4 or even 5 parents of a `scopename`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do a recursive join.

Here an example:
[Postgresql recursive self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261792/postgresql-recursive-self-join)

And here's the PostgreSQL doc:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html